generated class with Source generator does not work
i have a class which is working fine and when i change a property i can see that OnPropertyChanged(); and Save(); is fired/called
public class test : NotifiyingJsonSettings, IVersionable
{
    private System.Version version = new Version(1, 0, 0, 0);
    [EnforcedVersion("1.0.0.0")]
    public System.Version Version
    {
        get => version;
        set
        {
            version = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Version));
            Save();
        }
    }
    private string fileName = $"{AppContext.BaseDirectory}config.json";
    public override string FileName
    {
        get => fileName;
        set
        {
            if (fileName != value)
            {
                fileName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(FileName));
                Save();
            }
        }
    }
    private string test;
    public string Test
    {
        get => test;
        set
        {
            test = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Test));
            Save();
        }
    }
    private bool test2;
    public bool Test2
    {
        get => test2;
        set
        {
            test2 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Test2));
            Save();
        }
    }

}

so i decided to created a source generator to regenrated this class
[AutoSave]
public class AppConfig : NotifiyingJsonSettings, IVersionable
{
    [EnforcedVersion("1.0.0.0")]
    public Version Version { get; set; } = new Version(1, 0, 0, 0);
    public override string FileName { get; set; } = $"{AppContext.BaseDirectory}config.json";
    public virtual string Test { get; set; }
    public virtual bool Test2 { get; set; }
}

to this class:
public partial class AppConfig : Nucs.JsonSettings.Examples.NotifiyingJsonSettings, Nucs.JsonSettings.Modulation.IVersionable
{
    private System.Version version = new Version(1, 0, 0, 0);
    [EnforcedVersion("1.0.0.0")]
    public System.Version Version
    {
        get => version;
        set
        {
            if (version != value)
            {
                version = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
                Save();
            }
        }
    }
    private string fileName = $"{AppContext.BaseDirectory}config.json";
    public override string FileName
    {
        get => fileName;
        set
        {
            if (fileName != value)
            {
                fileName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
                Save();
            }
        }
    }
    private string test;
    public string Test
    {
        get => test;
        set
        {
            if (test != value)
            {
                test = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
                Save();
            }
        }
    }
    private bool test2;
    public bool Test2
    {
        get => test2;
        set
        {
            if (test2 != value)
            {
                test2 = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
                Save();
            }
        }
    }
}

now when i run my app, and i change a property, OnPropertyChanged(); and Save(); does not fired/called, i can confirm that source generator, generate my class (i used a File.WriteAllText() to see generator final output)

What tooling are you using? In visual studio, for example, you can check generator output under the "references" node in solution explorer, after expanding whatever reference is adding your generator. I'm a little confused, however; you can't change implementation using a generator - if one half of the file declared a property like FileName, the other half can't also declare such a property - partial properties are not currently s.thing. I also note that the type isn't marked partial

One way you can get around this is, instead of declaring public properties, you instead declare private variables which does the same generation (same way the CommunityToolkit.Mvvm does things). You will also need to set the partial keyword on the AppConfig class.
